# How to get angle of isometric drawing

Tags: technical-drawing

My sincerest apology if this question does not fit the platform, I need urgent help, which is why am posting here for the first time.

I am very new to Isometric drawing. I am given one sample and asked to redraw and change the color only. But my picture does not match the given sample. I can say that angles are different but do not understand what or how to change. Can anyone please help me?
The isometric method I followed in adobe illustrator is – for left- height 100%, vertical 86.602%, shear -30°, rotation -30°, and changed it accordingly for right and top.

Thank you. I just need some guidelines about angle or anything that can help me understand what am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have only applied the isometric changes to the smaller building with the peaked roof, at the front. All the other build have not changed, except for no shading to the rectangular building at the front.

Comment: Start by thinking what the thing looks like from above. now avoid having one building at 90 degrees and others in 45 it creates a uninteresting composition

Comment: In the reference sample, the top of the building on the right is not seen. This probably means that the viewer is at zero elevation. i.e. the viewer is not looking down on to the buildings. The reference is probably **not** made in a 3-d drawing software.